# T-SQL select all XML nodes as rows from RDL data

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, reporting-services, xpath

I'm trying to SELECT from a table containing XML column. I would like to obtain specific node and have a row created for each one.

The XML is directly obtained from Reporting Services database and contains RDL (report) structure. My goal is to display all `‹Textbox›‹Value›example‹/Value›‹/Textbox›` values for each report. The location of `‹Textbox›` nodes is unpredictable (it can be part of any element somewhere in XML structure).

Below is the current code, but for some reason id doesn't work:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#c') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #c

select top 50
     path as reportpath
    ,name as reportname
    ,convert(xml, convert(varbinary(max), content)) as reportxml
into
    #c  
from 
    reportserver.dbo.catalog
where 
    content is not null
order by creationdate desc

-----------------------------------------
DECLARE @x XML
SELECT @x = 
( SELECT 
     [reportpath]
    ,[reportname]
    ,[reportxml].query('
            for $a in //../Textbox
            return ‹Textbox
            valueX="{$a/Value}"
            /›
        ')
  FROM #c AS reports 
  FOR XML AUTO
)
select @x
-----------------------------------------
SELECT [reportpath]    = T.Item.value('../@reportpath', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       [reportname]    = T.Item.value('../@reportname', 'nvarchar(max)'),
       value     = T.Item.value('@value' , 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM   @x.nodes('//reports/Textbox') AS T(Item)
```

Example below shows sample "Textbox" containg a "Value":

```
          ‹RowGrouping›
            ‹Width›2.53968cm‹/Width›
            ‹DynamicRows›
              ‹Grouping Name="matrix1_OperationalWeek2"›
                ‹GroupExpressions›
                  ‹GroupExpression›=Fields!OperationalWeek.Value‹/GroupExpression›
                ‹/GroupExpressions›
              ‹/Grouping›
              ‹ReportItems›
                ‹Textbox Name="textbox35"›
                  ‹rd:DefaultName›textbox35‹/rd:DefaultName›
                  ‹Style›
                    ‹BackgroundColor›White‹/BackgroundColor›
                    ‹PaddingLeft›2pt‹/PaddingLeft›
                    ‹PaddingRight›2pt‹/PaddingRight›
                    ‹PaddingTop›2pt‹/PaddingTop›
                    ‹PaddingBottom›2pt‹/PaddingBottom›
                  ‹/Style›
                  ‹ZIndex›8‹/ZIndex›
                  ‹Value›=Fields!OperationalWeek.Value‹/Value›
                ‹/Textbox›
              ‹/ReportItems›
            ‹/DynamicRows›
          ‹/RowGrouping›
```

PS I had some trouble with stackoverflow code formatting so I replaced < and > marks with ‹ and ›. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Bret's Blog ([http://blogs.netconnex.com/2011/05/extracting-ssrs-report-rdl-xml-from.html][1])
and adding the namespace gets you results... I wish I could claim I understand well enough to explain but I mostly find my way by "stumbling" through it.

--================================================

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition',
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' AS rd --ReportDefinition
)
select top 50 
     c.Path as reportpath 
    --, c.name as reportname 
    ,t.value('@Name','VARCHAR(100)') as TextboxName
    ,t.value('data(Paragraphs/Paragraph/TextRuns/TextRun/Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as value 
from  
    reportserver.dbo.catalog c
cross apply 
    (select convert(xml, convert(varbinary(max), content))) as R(reportxml) 
cross apply 
--Get all the Query elements (The "*:" ignores any xml namespaces) 
    r.reportxml.nodes('//*:Textbox') n(t)        
where  
    content is not null 
    and c.Type = 2 -- Reports
order by creationdate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

**This simple XQuery**:

```
for $a in //Textbox             
 return 
   <Textbox             
      valueX="{$a/Value}"             
   />
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (namespace definition added to make it well-formed):

```
<RowGrouping xmlns:rd="rd">
  <Width>2.53968cm</Width>
  <DynamicRows>
    <Grouping Name="matrix1_OperationalWeek2">
      <GroupExpressions>
        <GroupExpression>=Fields!OperationalWeek.Value</GroupExpression>
      </GroupExpressions>
    </Grouping>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="textbox35">
        <rd:DefaultName>textbox35</rd:DefaultName>
        <Style>
          <BackgroundColor>White</BackgroundColor>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
        <ZIndex>8</ZIndex>
        <Value>=Fields!OperationalWeek.Value</Value>
      </Textbox>
    </ReportItems>
  </DynamicRows>
</RowGrouping>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Textbox valueX="=Fields!OperationalWeek.Value"/>
```

Therefore, if you cannot get result, your problem is in something else, not in the XQuery code.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'm still having problems finding the bug. My code does not return any 'Textbox' information. Perhaps it's related to encoding, I'm not yet sure how to fix that...

Answer (score 0):

I can't test if this works but it should do what you want.

```
select top 50
     path as reportpath
    ,name as reportname
    ,n.t.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(max)') as value
from 
    reportserver.dbo.catalog
cross apply
    (select convert(xml, convert(varbinary(max), content))) as c(reportxml)
cross apply
    c.reportxml.nodes('//Textbox') n(t)       
where 
    content is not null
order by creationdate desc
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns 0 rows. Maybe it's some sort of convertion problem or something related to XML structure... I'm still trying to find the solution