# Using SQL through SQL Server Management Studio : how to query SSRS Report properties details

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, properties, report

How can I query using SQL Server Management Studio, on the Report Server the contents of the SSRS Report properties set up?

[image]

Right click on the report - to pull this:

[image]

To obtain the contents in the following categories - especially the custom code:

[image]

I'm looking at what tables in SQL Server to query to obtain this information.

Comment: The page size info is in ReportSever.Catalog.Properties. It's XML so will need to be parsed.

Comment: @AlanSchofield thank you, what about the Code section is it also there?

Comment: I'm not sure. I doubt it. I would think that is embedded in the RDL definition which is in the content column rather than the properties column

Comment: @AlanSchofield thank you, i'm trying to figure out how to translate that xml to sql.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Answer to the question**: It is not possible, the reports are not stored in a table.

Custom Reports generated by SSMS are saved as an .rdl file on the report server, which is an xml-File.

You could query this xml with [functions provided by your SQL-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-ver16). It may be necessary to save the xml in a table to use these functions.
The Schema-Definition is provided by Microsoft on this [website](https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd).

Maybe this older question on stackoverflow may help getting started.
[T-SQL select all XML nodes as rows from RDL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741368/t-sql-select-all-xml-nodes-as-rows-from-rdl-data)